# How can I call PHP function when I use HTML?

Tags: php, html, function

I'm so new on Php and HTML. I have a problem about calling function. I think I've done what i read  on other articles but it's obvious i miss something.

My file is "login.php". I try to call a function by onclick method but it doesn't work.

My button to call the function:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-right: 10px;margin-top: inherit;" onclick="signin()">Sign In</button>
```

My function:

```
<script>

  function signin() {           
      <?php echo "hello"; ?>               
  };   

</script>
```

When I click to the button, on console it says:

> login.php:63 Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined

Or I tried to write function like this:

```
<?php 

function signin() { echo "hello"; }; 

?>
```

But now console says:

> login.php:33 Uncaught ReferenceError: signin is not defined

I appreciate your helpful answers from now. Thank you!

Comment: `function signin() {           
      alert("<?php echo'hello';?>");               
  }`

Comment: Use Ajax to have execute PHP

Comment: @Anant, some additions to your comment <script> function signin() { alert("<?php echo 'hello';?>"); } </script>

Comment: @Shudmeyer  he have `<script></script>` already

Comment: @Anant, added also space between echo and 'hello'

Comment: @Shudmeyer  that will not create any problem, but good though

Comment: @Anant thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

On client side you cannot call php functions directly from event handler. You have to implement a JavaScript method which calls a server side php script. Here an example based on [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

HTML

```
<button>Click</button>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('button').click(function() {
            $.get('your-php-file.php');
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP (your-php-file.php)

```
<?php
function signin() {...}

signin();
```

Very simple and untested example. Only for demonstration.